# Splitting lines that end in both '\n' as well as '\n\n'

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Forgive me if this is not the proper place to ask such a question but I am having the hardest time coming up with a viable way to split some text.

Here is a sample of the text I'm attempting to split:

```
[Thu Feb  2 12:45:38 2017][428423.3] (file_name:0xcb61) Invalid variable type
call stack:
-----------
[0cb61:+33] larray, r#26, fp(3),
[031ff:Mug::Request.preHandlers+17] refcall, fp(1), string#245, # from: fp(1)
[0339d:Mug::Request.process+77] call, addr(0x80001d), -, # Mug::Request.preHandlers()
[02ffd:Mug::Request.recv+93] call, addr(0x800026), -, # Mug::Request.process()
[02d03:Mug::Connection.on_client+101] refcall, fp(0), string#734, # from: fp(0)
[14a5b:+4] refcall, fp(-2), string#3103, # from: fp(-2)
[1e24a:main+9664] eop, -, -,

[Thu Feb  2 14:09:07 2017][428423.8] Warning: writing 0 byte file (/the_directory/) to tar archive
[Thu Feb  2 18:55:27 2017][449547.25] Warning: writing 0 byte file (/the_directory/) to tar archive
[Fri Feb  3 12:21:33 2017][451135.3] (file_name:0xcb61) Invalid variable type
call stack:
-----------
[0cb61:+33] larray, r#26, fp(3),
[031ff:Mug::Request.preHandlers+17] refcall, fp(1), string#245, # from: fp(1)
[0339d:Mug::Request.process+77] call, addr(0x80001d), -, # Mug::Request.preHandlers()
[02ffd:Mug::Request.recv+93] call, addr(0x800026), -, # Mug::Request.process()
[02d03:Mug::Connection.on_client+101] refcall, fp(0), string#734, # from: fp(0)
[14a5b:+4] refcall, fp(-2), string#3103, # from: fp(-2)
[1e24a:main+9664] eop, -, -,
```

As you can see above, the text above doesn't really fit any sort of pattern, and there are some errors that throw blank newlines, and some that do not.  Ideally what I want to end up with is something like this...

```
[[Thu Feb  2 14:09:07 2017][428423.8] Warning: writing 0 byte file (/the_directory/) to tar archive], [Thu Feb  2 12:45:38 2017][428423.3] (file_name:0xcb61) Invalid variable type \ncall stack:\n-----------\n[0cb61:+33] larray, r#26, fp(3),\n[031ff:Mug::Request.preHandlers+17] refcall, fp(1), string#245, # from: fp(1)\n[0339d:Mug::Request.process+77] call, addr(0x80001d), -, # Mug::Request.preHandlers()\n[02ffd:Mug::Request.recv+93] call, addr(0x800026), -, # Mug::Request.process()\n[02d03:Mug::Connection.on_client+101] refcall, fp(0), string#734, # from: fp(0)\n[14a5b:+4] refcall, fp(-2), string#3103, # from: fp(-2)\n[1e24a:main+9664] eop, -, -,]
```

And then I could access each error via a loop.  Right now I'm approaching this buy using a few regex's to filter on known good data and then just throwing away the call stack, but I'd like to be able to store the entire call stack if at all possible.

Here is my current code:

```
with open(local_dump, 'r') as ifile:
    for line in ifile:
        filename_pattern = re.compile(r'\((\w*\.\w*)\:\w*\)\s(.*$)')
        date_pattern = re.compile(r"^\[([a-zA-z]{3,})\s([a-zA-z]{3,})\s{2}(\d{1,2})\s(\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2})\s(\d{4})\]\[\d*\.\d*\]\s(.*$)")
        if re.search(date_pattern, line):
            data = re.search(date_pattern, line)
            if re.search(filename_pattern, (data[6])):
                data = re.search(filename_pattern, (data[6]))
                print("{0}: {1}".format(data.group(1),data.group(2)))
        else:
            if re.search("call stack", line.strip()):
                print(line.strip())
```

I was able to get this almost functional with this block of code:

```
    with open(local_dump, 'r') as ifile:
        lines = ifile.read()
        for line in lines.split('\n\n'):
            print("LINE: " + line)
```

The above code did break out the call stacks into their own line, but I ran into issues when the line ended with a '\n':

```
LINE: [Thu Feb  2 12:45:38 2017][428423.3] (file_name:0xcb61) Invalid variable type
call stack:
-----------
[0cb61:+33] larray, r#26, fp(3),
[031ff:Mug::Request.preHandlers+17] refcall, fp(1), string#245, # from: fp(1)
[0339d:Mug::Request.process+77] call, addr(0x80001d), -, # Mug::Request.preHandlers()
[02ffd:Mug::Request.recv+93] call, addr(0x800026), -, # Mug::Request.process()
[02d03:Mug::Connection.on_client+101] refcall, fp(0), string#734, # from: fp(0)
[14a5b:+4] refcall, fp(-2), string#3103, # from: fp(-2)
[1e24a:main+9664] eop, -, -,
LINE: [Thu Feb  2 14:09:07 2017][428423.8] Warning: writing 0 byte file (/the_directory/) to tar archive
[Thu Feb  2 18:55:27 2017][449547.25] Warning: writing 0 byte file (/the_directory/) to tar archive
[Fri Feb  3 12:21:33 2017][451135.3] (file_name:0xcb61) Invalid variable type
call stack:
-----------
[0cb61:+33] larray, r#26, fp(3),
[031ff:Mug::Request.preHandlers+17] refcall, fp(1), string#245, # from: fp(1)
[0339d:Mug::Request.process+77] call, addr(0x80001d), -, # Mug::Request.preHandlers()
[02ffd:Mug::Request.recv+93] call, addr(0x800026), -, # Mug::Request.process()
[02d03:Mug::Connection.on_client+101] refcall, fp(0), string#734, # from: fp(0)
[14a5b:+4] refcall, fp(-2), string#3103, # from: fp(-2)
[1e24a:main+9664] eop, -, -,
```

Here is how the text looks in a more raw format:

```
'[Thu Feb  2 14:09:07 2017][428423.8] Warning: writing 0 byte file (/the_directory/) to tar archive \n[Thu Feb  2 18:55:27 2017][449547.25] Warning: writing 0 byte file (/the_directory/) to tar archive \n[Fri Feb  3 12:21:33 2017][451135.3] (file_name:0xcb61) Invalid variable type \ncall stack:\n-----------\n[0cb61:+33] larray, r#26, fp(3), \n[031ff:Mug::Request.preHandlers+17] refcall, fp(1), string#245, # from: fp(1)\n[0339d:Mug::Request.process+77] call, addr(0x80001d), -, # Mug::Request.preHandlers()\n[02ffd:Mug::Request.recv+93] call, addr(0x800026), -, # Mug::Request.process()\n[02d03:Mug::Connection.on_client+101] refcall, fp(0), string#734, # from: fp(0)\n[14a5b:+4] refcall, fp(-2), sting#3103, # from: fp(-2)\n[1e24a:main+9664] eop, -, -, '
```

Thanks for any tips, tricks, and help you are able to provide.

Comment: Have you tried `lines.split('\n')`?

Comment: @PeterKuebler - I have, sorry, left that out in my rush to write it up.  The issue with that is that the call stack has '\n' littered throughout, it's a bit of a mess to go through.

Comment: Ah I didn't realize you wanted to keep those... Instead of that `for` loop, try to just escape the \ by calling `lines.replace('\\', '\\\\');` then `print(lines)` without the for loop.

Comment: The regex `\n{1,2}` is what you're looking for, but I'm not familiar to Python 3.x to know if you can pass a regular expression as the separator in `.split()`.

Comment: I don't understand what the expected output is suppose to be (it isn't valid python and it is all on one really large line). It almost looks like you are trying to split on the printed dates? So group anything together between the dates.

Comment: @AaronTaggart so ultimately what I'll be doing with this is parsing out error messages to see if its an error message we want to worry about or not.  Most of the error messages a single string and I can parse those no issue.  The ones that are giving me issues are the 'call stack' errors that span multiple lines.  Looking at the example I gave above, I'd like to use 'file_name_0xcb61' as my key, and the value to be the call stack error below it, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split on `\n` then remove empty lines.

```
input = "your input"
list = input.split("\n")
list = filter(None, list)
```

If you just want to get all error message from log you can try:

```
matches = re.finditer(r"\[.*?\]\[.*\]\s*(.*)$", input, re.MULTILINE)
for match in matches:
    print("Error: " + match.group(1))
```

Supposing all errors are preceded by two `[...]` groups

Comment: While this didn't give me exactly what I wanted with the "call stack" errors, this is a great response and helps me out tremendously.  Marking this as the answer, thank you!